# A new blank page is created bofore the plot when inserting a plot into a landscape page using pdflscape

Tags: pdflscape

I am inserting a picture into a file. To make the page landscape, I used the "pdflscape" package, but it creates a blank page before the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}    
  \begin{landscape} 
    \includegraphics{1.png}
  \end{landscape}   
\end{document}
```

How can I get rid of the blank page?

Comment: This does not happen with me. It could be that your image is too large to fit on the first page, which then flushes it to the second? Does it visually fit on "page 2"? Do you receive any warnings (like overfull boxes) in your `.log`?

Comment: Related question, [errors - Blank pages getting inserted between figures - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286037/250119)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, packages `pdflscape` and `lscape` do not insert blank pages (they only start new pages).
But TeX might do, if the object is too large to fit on the page. Check your `.log` file for overfull `\vbox` messages.

The following example increases the image as much as possible and ignores rounding errors that could cause overfull `\vbox` messages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picture}
\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \centering
    \makebox(\linewidth,\textheight){%
      \includegraphics[
        width=\linewidth,
        height=\textheight,
        keepaspectratio
      ]{1.png}%
    }%
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```