# Trying to display a 40 x 40 table in landscape mode

Tags: tables, landscape, alignat

My first problem was just trying to get the table to look OK. I did this by adding a "double align" (two &'s between elements) and a `\tiny` font size. When I put the table in landscape mode, I get a blank page before the table is displayed. I have tried fixing it by using many of the other answers to this problem, but none of them have worked.

Here is the partial code, without the complete table.

```
\begin{landscape}
\tiny
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{80}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{alignat*}{80}
0,&&0,&&0,&&0,..........
....
....
\end{alignat*}
```

I realize there might not be an elegant solution to this, and that the table is probably overflowing. I am happy enough with the resut as it is displayed, but the blank page before it needs to be removed. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does the answer to this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86019/a-new-blank-page-is-created-bofore-the-plot-when-inserting-a-plot-into-a-landsca

Comment: I tried that. It did not help. Thank you.

Comment: What's the purpose of having additional empty columns between the data columns?

Comment: I have never read such a large table. I might have seen one, but I haven't read one. Is someone going to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use a TABstack.  Key points for the first MWE (alternative form given later in the answer):

1. I invoke uniform column width with `\fixTABwidth{T}`
2. One can set the column gap with `\setstacktabbedgap{length}`
3. I have demonstrated a few 2-digit entries, to demonstrate right-alignment of matrix columns.
4. If you don't like the parens on the matrix, replace `\parenMatrixstack` with a `\tabbedCenterstack`.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{3pt}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize\[
\parenMatrixstack[r]{
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&19,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&21,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In response to the OP's comment about several wide columns, horizontal space can be conserved by turning off `\fixTABwidth{T}` and going from `\footnotesize` to `\tiny`.  One can also reduce the value of `\setstacktabbedgap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{2pt}
\begin{document}
\tiny\[
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&234519,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&21,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one needs for the matrix to exceed the horizontal margins in a symmetric fashion, one can force the extra-wide matrix into a box of the `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{2pt}
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill\par
Above shows the margin width
\tiny\[
\makebox[\textwidth]{\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&234519,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&21,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~\\
0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&
   0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&0~
}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction. I should have mentioned in my original question that I have some 6 digit entries, which makes this solution overflow by a lot, even with `\tiny`, `\setstacktabbedgap{1pt}` and `landscape`. I think part of what made the `alignat8` version OK was that I wasn't getting uniform colums. So the coulmns with entries that were all small, would just stay small. As is, the page cuts off at around the 25th column.

Comment: @bigtextable To make column widths fit the data, remove the `fixTABwidths{T}` macro.  I will edit.

Comment: Great. It just baaaaaaaarely fits now, which is as good as I can hope for. Can I set a larger gap in between rows?

Comment: @bigtextable Does the "barely fit" refer to horizontal or vertical?  There are methods for extending past margins on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: In landscape mode, I'm referring to the horizontal which is just barely fitting now. It looks like there is an inch between the last column and the page edge. I don't see how this can be improved, and it is good enough for me. I am asking about rows because I have extra space there that I would to use to make the table less crammed.

Comment: @bigtextable the vertical spacing can be adjusted or stretched by using `\renewcommand{\Lstackgap}{1.5\baselineskip}`. Increase or decrease the value `1.5\baselineskip` as you wish. Place the  renewcommand before `\tabbedCenterstack[r]{`.